# Jquery validation checking if word from input is the same as in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Okay so I have javascript variable with array of champions from game different names and such and I want to check if user inputted any of those names which has to be required so you cannot put whatever you want to submit the form it must be one of the champions from array.

Here is smaller array to not spam

```
var champions = [
            "Aatrox", "Ahri", "Akali"
        ];
```

And here is the form:

```
case 2:

$formid = $_POST['formid'];
            $formid += 1;
            $champ_number = $_POST['champ_number'];
            echo '<form id="second_form" action="#" method="POST" style="margin: 0;"  >';
                echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$formid.'" name="formid">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$champ_number.'" name="champ_number">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="patch" value="'.$_POST['patch'].'">';
                echo '<h1>Champion names:</h1>';
                for($i=1;$champ_number>=$i;$i++){
                    if($i==1&&$champ_number!=1){
                        echo '<input class="champion" type="text" placeholder="Champion '.$i.'"name="champno'.$i.'" required autofocus><br/>';
                    }
                    elseif($champ_number!=$i){
                        echo '<input class="champion" type="text" placeholder="Champion '.$i.'"name="champno'.$i.'" required><br/>';
                    }
                    elseif($champ_number==1){
                        echo '<input class="champion" type="text" placeholder="Champion '.$i.'"name="champno'.$i.'" required autofocus>';
                    }
                    else{
                        echo '<input class="champion" type="text" name="champno'.$i.'" placeholder="Champion '.$i.'" required>';

                    }
                }

                echo '<br/><input type="submit" value="next">';
            echo '</form>';
        break;
```

Here is also a picutre of how it looks right now :

[image: http://imgur.com/XN1xILK]

and under those suggestions there is a next button and I don't want user to be able to go further without typing the exact name of champion or selecting one

Comment: I see nothing here about the jQuery Validate plugin. You have not even shown any jQuery or JavaScript code.  Removing tag.  If you want help with these things, you have to show what you're doing and what you've already tried.   Since you're asking about JavaScript, all that matters is the ***rendered*** HTML markup as seen by the browser, not the PHP.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if an element exists in an array with [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

**Update:** This will check multiple inputs and return if they all exist in the array.

```js
var champions = ["one", "two", "three"];

//some inputs don't exist in champions
var inputs = ["four", "two", "one"];

var allFound = inputs.every(function(i) {
  return champions.indexOf(i) > -1;
});

console.log(allFound); //false

//All inputs now exist in champions
var inputs = [ "two", "one"];

var allFound = inputs.every(function(i) {
  return champions.indexOf(i) > -1;
});

console.log(allFound); //true
```

The key here is making sure the result of `indexOf` (which is a position) is making sure the result is greater than `-1`.

**Update 2:** I had to do some research to get this one working, but hopefully it'll do what you're after.

```js
var config = {
  fillAll: true
};

var champions = ["one", "two", "three"];

document.forms["myform"].oninput = function(e) {
  var champion = this["champion"];

  //Force into array
  if (champion[0] === undefined)
    champion = [this["champion"]];

  var reached = {
    valid: 0,
    unique: 0
  };

  var inputs = [].map.call(champion, function(n) {
    return n.value
  }).filter(function(n) {
    return n.length
  });

  var valid = [].every.call(champion, function(n, i) {
    n.setCustomValidity("");
    if (config.fillAll) return (reached.valid = i, champions.indexOf(n.value) > -1);
    else return n.value ? (
      reached.valid = i,
      champions.indexOf(n.value) > -1
    ) : true;
  });

  var unique = inputs.slice(0).sort().every(function(n, i, a) {
    reached.unique = inputs.lastIndexOf(n);
    return n != a[i - 1];
  });

  //Check for valid champions
  if (!valid) {
    champion[reached.valid].setCustomValidity("This is not a valid champion, please correct this field and resubmit.")
  }

  //Check for duplicates
  if (!unique) {
    champion[reached.unique].setCustomValidity("This champion has already been entered.")
  }

  this.checkValidity();
};
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  <input type="text" name="champion" placeholder="Champion 1">
  <input type="text" name="champion" placeholder="Champion 2">
  <input type="text" name="champion" placeholder="Champion 3">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Trying to implement it still. It doesn't check if there is only 1 input and another thing is when I have those tooltips helping you to get the name of the champion right if you click it it won't accept it you need to type it by yourself

Comment: I think at this point it's getting a little specialized - my script looks at the inputs that are there and validates them.  You could use another script for adding/removing inputs for multiple champions, then feed it to my script :).  What do you mean if you click the tooltip it won't accept?  Those are browser-supplied validation error tooltips - I don't think they have any more functionality that displaying a message.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'm getting just more and more confused with javascript. When i start typing for ex. K it will show up Kalista Karma etc. so you don't have to type it all out you just need to choose one and when you do it validation will not accept it and if i type the name of the same champion without clicking on tooltip it will work which is really odd.

Comment: Ah, are you using a jQuery autocomplete library, or are you using the browser input suggestions?  It seems to be working fine for me if I use a `datalist` with the input.

Comment: Jquery autocomplete which might be why is there anyway to use datalist with the same variable from javascript? so i wouldn't have later on to update both of those lists since thye have over 100 champions?

Comment: Sure, just populate the `datalist` element the same way you would any other element (`appendChild`).  If jQuery's autocomplete has an event that fires when it fills in a suggestion, you could move my input function into its own thing, set it as the callback for `oninput`, and call it from the autocomplete event.

Comment: That is working thank you very much!! Last question if I may, is there any way to make e.g. name="champno[]" start with 1 instead of 0 like in regular arrays? later on in code i start loops from 1 and i would ahve to make a lot of changes to correct that and I don't want to mess everything up

Comment: and I still have problem when there is only 1 input it won't check it

Comment: Zero-based indexing is how nearly everything in works, but if you wanted a quick fix, you could just subtract 1 from the iterator in your loop (`i` typically) when you get your reference to `champion`.  I'll update the example to check only fields that are filled out.

Comment: I'm mostly concerned about the 1 input problem http://jsfiddle.net/e3o2dgqe/2/ delete e.g. first 2 inputs and try validating and it will not work unfortunately

Comment: Just fixed it :) by the way, you can remove the `championValid` hidden field, I was using that while developing the original answer and ended up scrapping that idea.  I just forgot to remove the field.

Comment: Still can't get it to work with only one input :( drives me nuts I'm tinkering with it but noothing comes out of it http://jsfiddle.net/e3o2dgqe/3/

Comment: @Higeath Should be working with one input now, the problem was I was checking validity in a loop, but there is nothing to loop through if there is only one element.  Forcing the element into an array seems to work!  http://jsfiddle.net/e3o2dgqe/4/

Comment: But when you have 2 inputs now you can put in the first one something form array e.g. 'one' and then submit and it won't force you to fill the other input

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted, haha.  Do you want to force the user to fill all inputs with valid champions?  I added a `config` object with a `fillAll` flag to the example.  Set `fillAll` to `true` to force all fields to be filled out, or `false` to ignore empty fields.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/)

```
if ($.inArray("inputValue", champions) !== -1) {
    //entered value is in the array
}
```

Comment: anyway to do it with validation plugin?